# CA2204 warning for mentioning type name in string literal

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-analysis

Consider the following C# code:

```
if (atr == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("No ContentProperty attribute found on type.");
```

When building the project, a "*`CA2204`: Literals should be spelled correctly*" warning is issued because of unrecognized word "ContentProperty".

I am aware that I could disable the rule (either globally or for the containing method only) or create a custom Code Analysis dictionary and add "ContentProperty" in it as a recognized word. However, none of these solutions sounds appealing to me. Referring to a type or class member name in an exception message is bound to happen quite a lot in my project, which is an application framework.

***Does Code Analysis has a way to tell that a word / group of words isn't meant to be spell-checked***, like when surrounded by quotation marks or something? Or is disabling the warning the only way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Visual Studio 2017 <sup>†</sup>, I have demonstrated that Code Analysis warning [CA2204: Literals should be spelled correctly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2204-literals-should-be-spelled-correctly?view=vs-2019) can be avoided by using the [following additions to C# version 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-version-history#c-version-60):

- [$ - string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated), and
- [nameof operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof).

```cs
if (atr == null)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException(
        $"No {nameof(ContentProperty)} attribute found on type.");
}
```

You may also find [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56011872/1497596) to [String Interpolation in Visual Studio 2015 and IFormatProvider (CA1305)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32076823/1497596) for avoiding [CA1305: Specify IFormatProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1305-specify-iformatprovider?view=vs-2019) to be helpful.

---

† Note that C# version 6 was delivered with Visual Studio 2013. A newer version of Visual Studio (with a newer version of Code Analysis) might also be necessary to avoid this warning.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a different approach - as maintaining the Custom Dictionary  might become a maintenance issue: there's no link to the actual class (in your example the `ContentPropertyAttribute`). What happens if somebody renames or removes that class? The entries in the Custom Attributes must be synchronized manually which is error-prone.

Instead, I suggest using a bit of (dare I say it) reflection to inject the corresponding part of the string (instead of Resources that might end in having [CA1703](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264483.aspx)). Your example might be rewritten as:

```
throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("No {0} found on type.", typeof(ContentPropertyAttribute).Name);
```

Now you even have compile time safety for your message.

Comment: Unfortunately that will work for types only. As I said in my question, I will refer to types *and* members. Still, that's a valuable answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This article describes how to create a custom dictionary for code analysis: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514188.aspx

Create a file called CustomDictionary.xml and add it to your project. Set the Build Action property of the file to **CodeAnalysisDictionary**

The content of the file should look like this:

```
<Dictionary>
    <Words>
        <Recognized>
            <Word>ContentProperty</Word>
        </Recognized>
    </Words>
</Dictionary>
```

As suggested by Dr Willy's Apprentice in comments below it might be a good idea to dynamically generate a dictionary based on the framework's architecture.

Comment: As I said, a custom dictionary isn't a viable solution in my scenario. It's likely that I will have many properties and types references in my exception messages. Having to maintain a dictionary for each and every of them won't be efficient. Plus, it will make refactoring even harder than it already is.

Comment: I think that a nice next step to build on top of this answer (although I think it would be a lot of work) would be to create a [custom code generator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166817.aspx) that actually generates the content of this CustomDictionary.xml file based on the types, methods, properties, etc. in the project, as well as any referenced projects if possible. That way you wouldn't have to manually keep it updated.   EDIT: Sorry, the link I gave is probably not correct for this purpose, as that is regarding a single input file code generator.

Comment: Hmmm, that's indeed an interesting idea. :) But could that be too much? I don't want Code Analysis to take forever to complete because it has to analyze a huge dictionary file. :p

Comment: You could create a custom attribute to tag your code with. After that you could use reflection to find those tagged types and export them into a generated dictionary file. Or if all types and properties could wind up in the exception text then skip the tag and go all out and export them all.

Comment: @Crono1981 I have no idea how it would impact the performance of the code analysis. Perhaps you could make a bogus CustomDictionary.xml file and fill it up with thousands of random words to see how it affects performance. Or it probably wouldn't take too long to make a console program that uses Reflection to extract all of the actual type names, methods, properties, etc. from your current assembly just to get a version based on the current code. Hmm, rather than making a custom code generator, perhaps you could just kick off that console program each time prior to starting code analysis.

Comment: It's overkill but that would definitely solve the size issue, while keeping maintenance a breeze. I have to make it smart though, because I can't say I like polluting my code with too much attributes. Maybe I can put one on a type and have the dictionary generator assume that I want both the type and it's public members considered as valid words...

Comment: I wish there would be another way, though... it would be nice if Code Analysis could detect quotations marks within a string literal and ignores anything between.

Comment: @Dr.Wily'sApprentice can you add your comment as an answer? I think generating a dictionary dynamically is as close as the best answer anyone can come up with. I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: @Crono1981 Thanks, though I feel like Fredrik should get most of the credit for identifying the custom dictionary mechanism that the code analysis uses.

Comment: @Dr.Wily'sApprentice As Crono1981 pointed out "create a custom Code Analysis dictionary and add "ContentProperty" in it as a recognized word. However, none of these solutions sounds appealing to me." is in the question, which my brain happily filtered out, so feel free to post your comment as an answer and take the glory :)

Comment: I wish I could accept two answers :) Truth is you both have one part of the solution but since I already knew about custom dictionaries I feel @Dr.Wily'sApprentice intervention has been more useful here. So yes I too feel he should have credit.

Comment: Downvoted becuse `<Recognized><Word>` is not meant to store compound-words, unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to get CA2204 to recognise compound words.

Answer (score 2):

> Does Code Analysis have a way to tell that a word isn't meant to be spell-checked, **like when surrounded by quotation marks** or something?

CA2204 **only** applies to string literals, i.e. strings that are hard-coded (surrounded by quotation marks).  Disabling this code analysis rule will not prevent CA from checking the spelling on your class names, public members, or other code properties.

If your project is an application framework, where most/all string literals will be targeted at developers (like exception messages), I would recommend disabling this rule.  To me, that makes more sense than coming up with a complicated method of excluding every unrecognized string in exception messages.

Another option would be to move the "misspelled" strings into a `Resource.resx` file.  However, you'll have the same problem if [CA1703](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264483.aspx) is enabled.

Comment: CA1703 is enabled indeed. And I really meant quotations marks *within* string literals, like "This is my /"literal/" string.".